# No <target> in XLIFF file exported from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring, xliff

When I export my XLIFF file from Xcode, none of the strings I declared with NSLocalizedString have a < target> element. The strings generated from my storyboard do have a < target> element. Has anyone seen this before? Google reveals nothing.

String:

```
let oops = NSLocalizedString("Oops!", comment: "Alert box header")
```

Resulting XLIFF:

```
  <trans-unit id="Oops!">
    <source>Oops!</source>
    <note>Alert box header</note>
  </trans-unit>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know specifically about XCode's behavior, but `<target>` is optional, so this is legal (although possibly inconvenient) XLIFF.  ([source: xliff 1.2](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#trans-unit))

You should be able to create add a `<target>` element during translation without problem, and most translation environments that support XLIFF should be able to do this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I knew it was valid, but it's going to be a pain to go through and add the target elements every time I export the file. I could write a macro to do it, but it seems like Xcode should be doing this anyway. Anyway, I'll keep looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

The are a lot of useful tools that you can use to automatically write the target. Check on the App Store looking for `xliff`... some of these tools are also free.

As example, XLiffy seems to be easy enough to use.